# Alpha Blending to remove seam in an image

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have stitched two images but in the final image there is a visible seam.  I am trying to use **Alpha blending** to remove that seam.  I know Alpha blending is applied using the `cvAddweight()` function, but in this the function parameters are two images,**alpha**, **beta** , **gamma** and desitination . I am taking `gamma=0`, `alpha=0.6`, `beta=0.4`.  What will be my two input source images and the destination image as the last part of my code is this->

```
IplImage* WarpImg = cvCreateImage
(cvSize(T1Img->width*2, T1Img->height*2), T1Img->depth, T1Img- >nChannels); 
cvWarpPerspective(T1Img, WarpImg, &mxH);
cvSetImageROI(WarpImg, cvRect(0, 0, T2Img->width, T2Img->height));
cvCopy(T2Img, WarpImg);
cvResetImageROI(WarpImg);
cvNamedWindow("WarpImg Img",1);
cvShowImage("WarpImg Img", WarpImg);
cvSaveImage("save.jpg",WarpImg);
```

My final Image is [image]

Comment: It doesn't appear as though you have obtained the correct warp matrix, see the desk at the front, in the image on the right the desk has finished which in the image on the left the bottle appears to overhang the floor. I think you should look into the method by which you obtain your warp matrix mxH.

Comment: @Chris Okay.I'll check that but right now my main concern is removing seam.Anyways Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I dont think alpha blending is your answer.  The seem is there due to the difference in lighting / exposure.  Alpha blending is a way of essentially having one image visible through another by means of weighted averaging the two images colors together.  Your right and your left images are backed by black.  If you simply alpha blend then you are essentially going to be weighting your images with a black background.  The resultant effect will simply be a darkening of both images.

2 potential other methods might be to look at the average color of both images at the seem, and adjust one up or down by 50% of the difference in brightness, and the other opposite by the other 50% (one goes up and the other down and the 50% makes it so that the overall brightness jump by either is only 50% of the difference).

The other might do a more complex image histogram technique where you try to widen or shrink the histogram of one side' image to the other as well as align them, and re-asign your color (in this case grayscale) via the new histograms.

Answer (score 0):

Pyramid/multiband blending should do a good enough job for you scenario. Try enblend: http://enblend.sourceforge.net