# Removing seam from Stitched image using pyramid blending?

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have stitched two images but there is a visible seam between them. I am thinking of using pyramid blending to remove the seam, using inspiration from [this website](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/11/13/just-a-simple-laplacian-pyramid-blender-using-opencv-wcode/).

In this they have implemented there own function in which they are inputting two images and a mask, but I have only the stitched image. What will be my input images and what will be the length of my Mask? For stiching the last is by using homography matrix and warpPerspective.

(I am also open to any other type of blending)

Comment: Similar to this (new) question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10801851/769220 Can you include an example of your current results? From the link, the image at the bottom seems to summarise what the mask does quite nicely, note that I had to click on the image to see the full example.

Comment: I believe, if this is what you want to do, you should warp your images (so they are in the correct position wrt each other) and then provide these two images to the blending function, with perhaps a mask spanning all the pixels of image 1?